# Is it possible to modify the structure of an Access encrypted backend?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a split database. Experimenting with the frontend, I was able to add fields to a table in the linked backend using VBA until I encrypted the backend with a password.

Is it possible to still add fields to tables in the backend using VBA in the frontend WITHOUT decrypting the backend manually?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be. Try these notes:

```
Sub AlterDB()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sDB As String
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim fld As Field

    ''Encrypted
    sDB = "Z:\Docs\Test.enc"

    ''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193474.aspx
    ''Password is case sensitive
    Set db = OpenDatabase(sDB, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=pW")

    ''Option with tabledef
    ''The table is currently closed
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("table1")
    Set fld = tdf.CreateField("NewField", dbText, 20)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld

    ''Option with DDL
    ssql = "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN AnotherNew Int"
    db.Execute ssql, dbFailOnError

End Sub

Sub ListFields()
    sDB = "Z:\Docs\Test.enc"
    Set db = OpenDatabase(sDB, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=FB")

    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("table1")
    For Each f In tdf.Fields
        Debug.Print f.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Of course it worked. I was missing the PWD part. Thanks again, @Remou. I just don't understand why it doesn't work when I leave the "False" out of the Options parameter in the syntax.

Comment: I am afraid that false is a quirk. Everywhere else you can get away with nothing, but as far as I remember, here you cannot.